# ExpressJS validation

Tags: express, validation

the following if condition does not work:

I still have the possibility to register with numbers instead of strings.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoVlN.png)

Comment: Don't post code in images, post it as text. Are you sure the data is sent to your server in the correct format? Just that something looks like a number doesn't mean it is sent to the server as a proper number.

Comment: yes the data is set to the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that `req.body.firstName` and `req.body.lastName` are coming in as a stringed numbers e.g.:

```json
{
   "firstName": "4",
   "lastName": "187"
}
```

so `typeof` will still consider them as strings. You can use a regex if you really hate numbers.

```js
const { firstName, lastName } = req.body;
if (firstName.match(/^\d*(\.\d+)?$/) || lastName.match(/^\d*(\.\d+)?$/)) {
  return res.status(422).json({
    message: 'Name provides letters, not numbers!',
  })
}
```

or I would suggest you use a validation library like [Joi](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.6.1) or [validate.js](https://validatejs.org/) to avoid building an API with possible security holes.